# Audio works in Chrome but not in Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, audio, safari

I have this snippet of code:

```
<audio id="audioFrenata"  controls="controls">
    <source src="http://myDNS/Teste123/v1" type="audio/x-wav">
    </audio>
```

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but the same code doesn't work in Safari. It does not give a console error.

To check whether WAV works in Safari, I tried this:

```
<audio id="audioFrenata"  controls="controls">
    <source src="assets/acmeTest1.wav" type="audio/x-wav">
    </audio>
```

This works fine in Safari.

How can I make the first example work in Safari?